# Send Sms through Python

Tags: python, www-authenticate

I'm using the following code to connect to a phone to send an SMS message:

```
import serial
import time

phone = serial.Serial()
phone.baudrate = 38400
phone.bytesize = 8
phone.stopbits = 1
phone.xonxoff = 0
phone.rtscts = 0
phone.timeout = 0
phone.port = 3  #try different ports here, if this doesn't work.
phone.parity=serial.PARITY_NONE
phone.open()
print phone.portstr


recipient = "+929409778"
message = "We did it!"
print ("I did come after it")
try:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'ATZ\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)




    phone.write(b'AT+CMGF=1\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(b'AT+CMGS="' + recipient.encode() + b'"\r')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(message.encode() + b"\r")

    print (message)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.write(bytes([26]))

    time.sleep(0.5)
    phone.readall()


finally:
    phone.close()
```

I am able to connect the phone, but I am not able to send the message. It's not giving me an error, so I'm not sure where to start debugging.

Is there something wrong with my code that I'm not seeing?

Comment: In the future, it helps when you use complete, coherent sentences with proper capitalization and punctuation. Avoid 'text speak' like 'plz' 'ur', etc.

Comment: "It's not giving me an error" How do you know?

Comment: ok will try doing that in the future.... 

@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams because it is not giving me a syntax error. the phone closes in the end that is how i know !

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the phone stream with phone.flush() and see if that sends it through.